# How to update Scala Version in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, scala, ubuntu

In Ubuntu terminal when I write the command below:

```
scala -version
```

It gives the following Output:

```
Scala code runner version 2.9.2 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
```

I want to update this to 2.11.8. I downloaded the tar file

> scala-2.11.8.tgz

and untared it to get

> scala-2.11.8

folder in "/home/hdadmin/" location.

But still when I check the scala-version again it shows the same 2.9.2 version.
It is picking scala version from

> /usr/bin/scala

instead of

> /home/hdadmin/scala-2.11.8

Is there a way to change this path?

I tried uninstalling & reinstalling scala using commands below:

```
sudo apt-get remove scala
sudo apt-get remove scala-library scala
sudo apt-get install scala
```

But the same version(2.9.2) gets installed because I think it comes by default with Java(1.8) that I have. There are some very unclear option online to update using sbt or deb or in the link http://osgux.tumblr.com/post/44635945407/install-scala-2-10-0-in-ubuntu.

I need to know if there is a direct way to update scala version.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to remove the `old scala` from your computer, you have to delete the previously extracted `scala` folder. To know the path to `old scala`

```
which scala
```

It will show you the path upto `..../bin/scala`

You can `delete` the parent folder (*before bin folder*) to remove the old scala.
For the `new scala` to be recognized by the system, the `executable binary file` path need to be put in `PATH` of the system if you haven't done so. Or you need to edit the path to point to the new `scala`.
As @Mureinik suggested, you need to set two variables in `~/.bashrc` file

```
export SCALA_HOME=/home/hdadmin/scala-2.11.8
```

And

```
export PATH=$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin
```

Then either you `restart your terminal` or do one of the following commands

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Or

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Now

```
scala -version
```

should show you the right version.

Comment: _Thankyou Ramesh for the reply..it was addition of scala path in .bashrc file that solved the issue_

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `/home/hdadmin/scala-2.11.8` at the beginning of your `$PATH`, so the executable is taken from there first:

```
export PATH=/home/hdadmin/scala-2.11.8:${PATH}
```

You can place this call in your `.bashrc` (or the equivalent in your own environment if you aren't using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SKDMAN](https://mungingdata.com/java/sdkman-multiple-versions-java-sbt-scala/), perhaps the easiest way to manage versions of not only scala, but also java, sbt and spark (among other things).